# Calling a parent method from a child class, encapsulation issues in Java

Tags: java, encapsulation

For some reason I can't figure out how to get this to compile. It cannot find the setValue function in this line: 'skill.get("Level").setValue(newLevel);'

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Stat extends GameObject
{
    int value;

    public Stat()
    {
        name = "Accuracy";
        value = 1;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {   
        return value;
}

    public void setValue(int newValue)
    {
        value = newValue;
    }
}


import java.util.HashMap; 

public class Skill extends Stat
{
    protected HashMap<String, GameObject> skill;

    public Skill()
    {
        name = "swords";
        description = "Learn how to master the art of swordmanship";
        skill.put("Level",new Stat("Level",1));
        skill.get("Level").setValue(newLevel);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any `get(String str)` or put method as well there is no constructor `Stat(String,int)` available, clearly confusing.

Comment: Trucated version of my GameObject Class:
   `public class GameObject
{
 String name, description;
 int number;
 protected HashMap<String, GameObject> object;
 public GameObject()
 {
  name = "Stat";
  object = new HashMap<String, GameObject>();
 }
 public GameObject get(String hashValue)
 {
  return object.get(hashValue);
 }
}`

Comment: I couldn't see the constructor of the Stat class "Stat("Level",1)" in the given code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

skill.get("Level") is a GameObject, not a Stat.

Probably setValue is only defined in Stat, not GameObject?

If you are sure (for instance if you checked with instanceof or only put Stat objects in the skill-HashMap) you can cast the result of the get to a Stat object, like this:

```
((Stat)skill.get("Level")).setValue(newLevel);
```

Edit: probably just a copy paste problem: you need a constructor Stat(String, int) (thanks to [Subhrajyoti Majumder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209513/subhrajyoti-majumder) for pointing that out)

Comment: exactly, does that mean i should do a typecast?

Comment: It depends. You could either do a typecast or put the setValue in your GameObject and override it in Stat. That's what I'd probably do, but it depends on what GameObject is ;)